# getData from milti tab/page formbuilder

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I can save and get the inputs from multiple tabs, but at the time of adding new input I can't get this one.

but fbInstances doesn't add the new elements.
It only has the elements that are initialized when the page loads. Also when I click 'save-all' I get Uncaught TypeError: fbInstances[i].actions.getData is not a function

```
var $formPages = $(document.getElementById("survey"));

jQuery(($) => {
    "use strict";
    
    obtenerEncuesta();
});
var fbInstances = [];
$formPages.tabs({
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.newPanel.selector === "#new-pageMostrar") {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
function obtenerEncuesta() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../handler/Json_encuestas.ashx",
        type: "post",
        data: { acc: 'ObtenerEncuesta', idEncuesta: 1 },
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data.Json_Encuesta)
            var stepLen = res.length;
            

            
            // var j;
            for (var i = 1; i <= stepLen; i++) {
                countFB = i + 1;
                var final_tab_id = countFB;
                var tabId = "pageMostrar-" + i.toString();
                
                
                const $newPageTemplate = document.getElementById("new-pageMostrar");
                const $newTabTemplate = document.getElementById("add-page-tab");
                const $newPage = $newPageTemplate.cloneNode(true);
                $newPage.setAttribute("id", tabId);
                $newPage.classList.add("fb-editor");
                const $newTab = $newTabTemplate.cloneNode(true);
                $newTab.removeAttribute("id");
                const $tabLink = $newTab.querySelector("a");
                $tabLink.setAttribute("href", "#" + tabId);
                $tabLink.innerText = "page " + i;

                $newPageTemplate.parentElement.insertBefore($newPage, $newPageTemplate);
                $newTabTemplate.parentElement.insertBefore($newTab, $newTabTemplate);
                $formPages.tabs().tabs("refresh");
                $formPages.tabs().tabs("option", "active", 0);
                var j = 0;
                //const formBuilder = $("#" + tabId).formBuilder( res[i] );
                const formBuilder = $($newPage).formBuilder();
                formBuilder.promise.then(function (fb) {
                    fb.actions.setData(res[j]);
                    fbInstances.push(fb);
                    j++;
                });

            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            init_notificacion('error', 'Lipigas Informa!', "Problema al obtener documento asociado!");
        }
    });
}


$(document.getElementById("save-all")).click(function (e) {

        var data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < fbInstances.length; i++) {
            data.push(fbInstances[i].actions.getData())
        }
        console.log(data);
    //var fbEditor = document.getElementsByClassName("fb-editor");
    //var formBuilder = $(fbEditor).formBuilder();
    //formBuilder.promise.then(function (fb) {
    //    console.log(fb.actions.getData());
    //});
    
});
```

```
<div id="survey">
  <ul id="tabs">
      <li id="add-page-tab"><a href="#new-page">+ Page</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="new-pageMostrar"></div>
</div>
                   
<div class="save-all-wrap"><button id="save-all" type="button">Save All</button></div>
```

i need that when i add new items i can get their data.

Comment: It might help more if you post the complete code.

Comment: If this is your complete code - how are you filling up the `fbInstances` array? What do you get when you log it to the console?